# How to parse multiline with awk without weird duplicates

Tags: bash, shell, awk, pattern-matching

I am trying to parse the output of pacman -Qi, it looks more or less like this:

```
Name            : zvbi
Version         : 0.2.35-3
Description     : VBI capture and decoding library
Build Date      : Fri 24 Aug 2018 09:48:59 CEST
Install Date    : Thu 30 Aug 2018 08:55:50 CEST
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature

Name            : zziplib
Version         : 0.13.69-1
Description     : A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
Build Date      : Wed 21 Mar 2018 21:16:20 CET
Install Date    : Thu 22 Mar 2018 11:13:19 CET
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

I need to parse it into this:

```
zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
zziplib    A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
```

White-spaces are tabs

Right now I tried to parse it with:
`pacman -Qi | awk -F: '/^Name/ {n=$2} /^Desc/ {d=$2} {print n "\t" d}'`

But it outputs this

```
 zvbi   
 zvbi   
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zziplib     VBI capture and decoding library
 zziplib     VBI capture and decoding library
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
```

And using uniq gives this

```
 zvbi   
 zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
 zziplib     VBI capture and decoding library
 zziplib     A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
```

Notice the space at the start of each lines.

I think it might be done by checking the state of the variables n and d, printing them when they both are set then emptying them, But i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: The standard `pacman -Ss zvbi zziplib` is not ok?

Comment: Even with pacman -Ss I would need parsing to get the required result since it prints more than needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
/^Name/{
  if(value){
     print value
  }
  sub(/.*: /,"")
  value=$0
  next
}
/^Description/{
  sub(/.*: /,"")
  value=(value?value OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(value){
    print value
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Ok this is very close but its missing the tab between the Description and the Name

Comment: @Lastrosade, ok sure done with editing, check now and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
$ awk -F': ' '/^Name/ {n=$2} /^Desc/ {print n "\t" $2}' file
zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
zziplib A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
```

The main problem with your script was that the `{print...}` block was being executed for every line of input rather than just when the `Desc`line was seen and then you weren't including the blank after the `:` in your FS so it was still present in each field.

Answer (score 0):

And I've written written this sed script:

```
pacman -Qi | sed -n '/^\(Name\|Description\)[[:space:]]*: /{s///;H}; /^$/ba; $ba; d; :a;x;s/^\n//;s/\n/\t/;p'
```

1. `/^\(Name\|Description\)[[:space:]]*: /{s///;H}; /^$/ba` - Each line that starts with `Name` and `Description` has the macthed part removed and is appneded to hold space.
2. `/^$/ba; $ba; d;` - If an empty line or an end of file is encountered, we branch to label a; Otherwise we start new cycle.
3. `:a;x;s/^\n//;s/\n/\t/;p` - In label a we exchange hold space with pattern space, remove leading newline (dunno where it's from), substitute first newline with a tab, and print the output.

Sample output:

```
zlib    Compression library implementing the deflate compression method found in gzip and PKZIP
zsh A very advanced and programmable command interpreter (shell) for UNIX
zstd    Zstandard - Fast real-time compression algorithm
zvbi    VBI capture and decoding library
zziplib A lightweight library that offers the ability to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file
```

Comment: Nice, I will use this in my script since it removes the awk dependency, Thanks a lot !